# How to edit existing activity zones in dwarf fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a pasture that I want to assign more animals to. I assume there must be a way to do this without deleting the pasture and creating a new one, but I really can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Zones menu with <kbd>i</kbd>, move the cursor over the pasture you want to edit, then press <kbd>N</kbd>. This screen will let you manage animals and assign them to that pasture.